# In Rails, how can I reliably look for a specific parameter when using nested routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Assume the following routes:

```
  resources :products do
    resources :images
  end
```

This creates the following routes:

```
          product_images GET    /products/:product_id/images(.:format)                                   images#index
                         POST   /products/:product_id/images(.:format)                                   images#create
       new_product_image GET    /products/:product_id/images/new(.:format)                               images#new
      edit_product_image GET    /products/:product_id/images/:id/edit(.:format)                          images#edit
           product_image GET    /products/:product_id/images/:id(.:format)                               images#show
                         PATCH  /products/:product_id/images/:id(.:format)                               images#update
                         PUT    /products/:product_id/images/:id(.:format)                               images#update
                         DELETE /products/:product_id/images/:id(.:format)                               images#destroy
                products GET    /products(.:format)                                                      products#index
                         POST   /products(.:format)                                                      products#create
             new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)                                                  products#new
            edit_product GET    /products/:id/edit(.:format)                                             products#edit
                 product GET    /products/:id(.:format)                                                  products#show
                         PATCH  /products/:id(.:format)                                                  products#update
                         PUT    /products/:id(.:format)                                                  products#update
                         DELETE /products/:id(.:format)                                                  products#destroy
```

Now assume I have a `ProductController` and a `ProductImageController` that both inherit from `ApplicationController`.  In `ApplicationController` I want to be able to have a property called `active_product` that is automatically set to the relevant product.  Something like the following:

```
def active_product
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
end
```

The problem here is that sometimes the parameter is called `:id` and sometimes it's called `:product_id`.  Is there a better pattern for being able to extract the value of the product id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, how about doing

```
def active_product
  @product = Product.find params[:product_id] || params[:id]
end
```

Comment: That's certainly an easy way to do what I need.  I guess my question is more: is what I'm trying to do an "against the grain" pattern?

Comment: Your logic application is fine. I'm not really familiar of what you're trying to build, but it's pretty DRY to me.